# Unable to print out a function

Tags: python

Hi I'm new to programming, and ran into some problems while practicing using python.

So basically my task is to create a simple quiz with (t/f) as the answer. So here's my code:

```
def quiz(question,ans):
    newpara = input(question)
    if newpara == ans:
       print("correct")
    else:
       print("incorrect")
    return(newpara)

quiz_eval = quiz("You should save your notebook: ","t")

print("your answer is ",quiz_eval)
```

When the user input something, this code prints:

```
your answer is  hi
```

However, I want it to print "`your answer is correct/incorrect`".

I'm not sure what has gone wrong here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should be returning either "correct" or "incorrect". You function returns the value of the input so it's normal to get that output. Try this:

```
def quiz(question,ans):
    newpara = input(question)
    if newpara == ans:
       answer= "correct"
    else:
       answer= "incorrect"
    return(answer)


quiz_eval = quiz("You should save your notebook: ","t")

print("your answer is ",quiz_eval)
```

Note that my answer is just to answer your question and give the output the way you want it. If your program requires to limit the input of the user to either "t" or "f", then you need to add more conditions in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was extremely helpful!

Comment: @SunVarunpaijit glad it helped. Please don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as the solution